# Trouble adding active class to buttons on website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add an active class to my buttons so that when you click on them the hover animation would stay on the active button. It seems like something in my javascript does not follow through with my call to add the active class to whatever element I put it on. pls help thnx ^_^

https://jsfiddle.net/purpkev/pf1vzx2t/7/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ukiyo Sushi ツ</title>
    <link href = "/style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src = "/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<div class = "hero active">
    <div class = "hero1">    
    <div class = "hero2">-->    
        <header id = "bg">
            <nav class = "navbar">
                <a href = "#" class = "logo">Ukiyo Sushi ツ</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href ="#" class = "about">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#" class = "menu">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#" class = "services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#" class = "contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav> 
            <div class = "sushiPlatter">
                <h2 id = "caption">Chef's Special Sushi Platter</h2>
                <div class = "dots">
                    <button class = "dot" onclick = "imgslider(1)"></button>
                    <button class = "dot" onclick = "imgslider(2)"></button>
                    <button class = "dot" onclick = "imgslider(3)"></button>
                </div>
                <a href = "#">View Menu</a>
            </div>
        </header>
    <!--</div>
    </div>
    </div>-->
    <section class = "idkYet">
        <div>
            <span>hello I am filler content</span>
        </div>    
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.dots{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin: 0 1em;
}

.dot{
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: solid 2px white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: .2em;
    transform: scale(.75);
    outline-color: white;
}

.active{
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: .25;
}

.dot:hover, .dot:hover, .dot:hover{
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: .25;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function buttonClick(){
   var button = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
   var dot = button.children;
   dot[0].classList.add("active");
   for(var i = 0; i < dot.length; i++){
         dot[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
         var active = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
         active[0].className = active[0].className.replace("active", "");
         this.className += "active";
      });
   }
}
```

edit:
I have tried suggestions in the comments but the active class still does not get added to the active button, here is what my code looks like:

```
function buttonClick(){
   var button = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
   var dot = button[0].children;
   dot[0].classList.add("active");
   for(var i = 0; i < dot.length; i++){
         dot[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
         var active = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
         active[0].className = active[0].className.replace("active", "");
         this.className += "active";
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns array.

Use `button[0].children` or `button = document.getElementsByClassName("dots")[0]`

I am not very good at vanilla javascript. I will do the equivalent of jQuery as follows

```
$('.dots').on('click', '.dot', function(e) {
  el = $(this);
  el.parents('.dots').find('dot').removeClass('active');
  el.addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I posted an edit of the main question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're adding eventListeners again and again.

Maybe try this approach, where you send the button element to the function using the "this" keyword....

(see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sre1dua9/1/  )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ukiyo Sushi ツ</title>
    <link href = "/style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src = "/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<div class = "hero active">
    <div class = "hero1">    
    <div class = "hero2">-->    
        <header id = "bg">
            <nav class = "navbar">
                <a href = "#" class = "logo">Ukiyo Sushi ツ</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href ="#" class = "about">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#" class = "menu">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#" class = "services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#" class = "contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav> 
            <div class = "sushiPlatter">
                <h2 id = "caption">Chef's Special Sushi Platter</h2>
                <div class = "dots">
                    <button class = "dot" onclick="window.imgslider(this, 1)"></button>
                    <button class = "dot" onclick="window.imgslider(this, 2)"></button>
                    <button class = "dot" onclick="window.imgslider(this, 3)"></button>
                </div>
                <a href = "#">View Menu</a>
            </div>
        </header>
    <!--</div>
    </div>
    </div>-->
    <section class = "idkYet">
        <div>
            <span>hello I am filler content</span>
        </div>    
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Then just track the last button clicked:

```
var lastDot = null;
window.imgslider = function(elem, x)
{  
   var bg = document.getElementById("bg");
   var dot = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
   var caption = document.getElementById("caption");
   switch(x){
      case 1:
         bg.style.backgroundImage = "-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.375), rgba(0,0,0,.375)),url(/img/header.jpg)";
         caption.style.marginLeft = "0em";
         caption.innerHTML = "Chef's Special Sushi Platter";
         break;
      case 2: 
         bg.style.backgroundImage = "-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.375), rgba(0,0,0,.375)),url(/img/pokebowl.jpg)";
         caption.style.marginLeft = "2em";
         caption.innerHTML = "Spring Poke Bowl";
         break;
      case 3:
         bg.style.backgroundImage = "-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.375), rgba(0,0,0,.375)),url(/img/ramen.jpg)";
         caption.style.marginLeft = "3.75em";
         caption.innerHTML = "Miso Ramen"; 
   }

 // do dots
   if(lastDot){
    lastDot.classList.remove("active");
  }
  elem.classList.add("active");

  // store last dot for next click
  lastDot = elem;
}
```